# How use provider in onGenerateRoute?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

How can i use my UserProvider in onGenerateRoute?
I want to check if user is logger using UserProvider.isLogged(), but when i trying to get Userprovider i must to pass context with i dont have in Router.

I already trying to change generateRoute to non-static and pass context by constructor to Router but it throw error.

main.dart

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MultiProvider(
      providers: <SingleChildCloneableWidget>[
        ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (_) => BottomNavigationBarProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (_) => UserProvider()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      onGenerateRoute: Router.generateRoute,
      title: 'Title,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
    ),);

}
}
```

Router.dart

```
class Router {

  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomePage());
        break;
      case '/login':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginPage());
        break;
      case '/register':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => RegisterPage());
        break;
      case '/terms':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => TermsPage());
        break;
      case '/home':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
          return HomePage();
        });
        break;
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                      child: Text('No route defined for ${settings.name}')),
                ));
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

===MY TRY===

main.dart

```
onGenerateRoute: Router(context).generateRoute,
```

Router.dart

```
class Router {
  Router(this.context);

  BuildContext context;

  Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    final UserProvider userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);
     userProvider.isLogged();
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomePage());
        break;
      case '/login':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginPage());
        break;
      case '/register':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => RegisterPage());
        break;
      case '/terms':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => TermsPage());
        break;
      case '/home':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) { 

          return HomePage();});
        break;
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                      child: Text('No route defined for ${settings.name}')),
                ));
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

This "My try" gives me error. How can i do that? "Could not find the correct ProviderProvider> above this MyApp widget."

Comment: did you got an solution for this ?

Answer (score 3):

In this case `context` does not include the provider. So it can be achieved by putting MaterailApp into builder method of MultiProvider, like:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context1) {

  return MultiProvider(
   providers: <SingleChildCloneableWidget>[
     ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (_) => BottomNavigationBarProvider()),
     ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (_) => UserProvider()),
   ],
   builder: (context2, _) =>  MaterialApp(
    initialRoute: '/',
    onGenerateRoute: Router(context2).generateRoute,
    title: 'Title',
    theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ),
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

Now `UserProvider` can be accessed from `context2` by calling `Provider.of<UserProvider>(context2)`