# Flutter: OnGenerateRoute Error "Invalid Constant Value"

Tags: flutter, dart, deep-linking

How to solve, "Invalid Constant Value" for OnGenerateRoute in Flutter.

I got this error while implementing Deeplinking, and it was due to the use of MultiProvider in my Main.dart file.

Comment: I think It would be better if you include the minimal reproducible example code.

Comment: remove the word "const"

Comment: Dude, I already fixed it, with the codes below!!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you need to create separate context for onGenerateRoute and others. Like the codes below...

Btw, these codes were taken from : [How use provider in onGenerateRoute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57275594/how-use-provider-in-ongenerateroute)

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context1) {

  return MultiProvider(
   providers: <SingleChildCloneableWidget>[
     ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (_) => BottomNavigationBarProvider()),
     ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (_) => UserProvider()),
   ],
   builder: (context2, _) =>  MaterialApp(
    initialRoute: '/',
    onGenerateRoute: Router(context2).generateRoute,
    title: 'Title',
    theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ),
   ),
  );
 }
}
```